# Survey gem not creating routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, survey

I just installed runtimerevolution's `survey gem` and used `rails generate survey plain namespace:tests` per the documentation to get a scaffold and CRUD framework.

Although it said in the console it added routes into `routes.rb` it did not. I'm just wondering if someone can tell me what I should add to my `routes.rb` to be able to access the view pages created by the gem.

EDIT:

bundle exec rake db:migrate does the following:

```
== 20150805161555 CreateSurvey: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:survey_surveys)
   -> 0.0070s
-- create_table(:survey_questions)
   -> 0.0010s
-- create_table(:survey_options)
   -> 0.0020s
-- create_table(:survey_attempts)
   -> 0.0010s
-- create_table(:survey_answers)
   -> 0.0020s
== 20150805161555 CreateSurvey: migrated (0.0190s) ============================


$ rails generate survey routes namespace:tests


DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      insert  config/routes.rb
Generation of Routes Template Complete :) enjoy Survey
```

Comment: Did you run `rails generate survey:install`? as indicated by the documentation http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/survey/0.2#Installation

Comment: Yes I did which is why I find it so odd that the routes didn't take

Comment: You may need to generate the route separately `rails generate survey routes namespace:tests`

Comment: When you type '$bundle exec rake routes'  does anything come up showing survey routes?

Comment: Hi Rob. I tried running that prior to posting, and again now as you suggested, it does say ' insert  config/routes.rb' but doesn't actually write to the file

Comment: Brian I did as you suggested and no mention of survey routes shows up